# Spring Cloud Config - config loaded twice and without profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have problem with properly configuring spring cloud config. I have dependencies

```
<spring.cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring.cloud.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Boostrap.yml

```
spring:
  application.name: myapp
  profiles:
    active: dev
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://ip:8888
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      username: admin
      password: secret
```

Now when my application starts it loads config twice. The first load is by class `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator` and is without expected profile. The second is by `ConfigServerConfigDataLoader` and this time it is with proper profile. It seems that the configs loaded during first load takes precedence and my application does not start.

```
12:32:54 [ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator:241] - Fetching config from server at : http://ip:8888
12:32:54 [ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator:165] - Located environment: name=myapp, profiles=[default], label=null, version=7d2bc5d68acd8fcca65f34f2074b1860f36e19c6, state=null
12:32:54 [MyApplication:646] - The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
12:32:54 [ConfigServerConfigDataLoader:255] - Fetching config from server at : http://ip:8888
12:32:54 [ConfigServerConfigDataLoader:255] - Located environment: name=myapp, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=7d2bc5d68acd8fcca65f34f2074b1860f36e19c6, state=null
```

Providing profile using param `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` does not help. How to configure profile that can be read by boostrap?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? for me the service tries to fetch 3 times from the config server on startup

Answer (score 0):

Add file resources -> bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=myapp
spring.profiles.active=dev
# ip and port of the config server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```